# IOS replicate "drop pin" effect

Tags: objective-c, ios, animation, core-animation, ios5

I am having a custom 'tableview' implementation. I am implementing a feature which I want to animate by showing the "drop pin" effect. This effect is shown in the popular Google Maps app.

how do I mimic this animation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't seem like much of an effect -- it's really just an image of a pin moving from the top of the screen to someplace in the middle. A basic UIView animation with an appropriate animation curve would probably do it. Is there something in particular you're having trouble with?

Comment: Caleb, after repeatedly seeing the animation i think u r right.All I need to do is animate some image dropping onto the main view coordinates. I think I got it....

Comment: Maybe go with UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn to give some sense of acceleration followed by a sudden stop.